# Parse/PFQueryTableView : Append extra text to an object in parse

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, uilabel

How to append a text or space before or after a text to an object in parse.

I want to add # before any text in one object.

```
  cell.TextLabel.text = object?.objectForKey("Hashtag") as? String
```

I get error when I try to do like this:

```
cell.TextLabel.text = "# " + object?.objectForKey("topic") as? String
```

Without parse I can Add it simply without any error:

```
cell.TextLabel.text = " # " + test[indexpath.row]
```

Comment: xcode advice me to change it to  + error to change it again and again without ending >>`cell. TextLabel.text = "# " + (object?.objectForKey("topic"))! as? String`

Comment: The error sounds like the cell does not contain a TextLabel ... And the Xcode advice points to that the problem lies in the fact that the object is nullable, which probably is not accepted in the string concatenation. Try to assign the object?.objectForKey("topic") to a non-nullable string, setting the string to "" in case the object is nil, and use that string to set your text field value.

Comment: Ok I made changes and it works with strange and complicated code                  `cell. TextLabel.text = "#" + ((object?.objectForKey("topic"))! as! String) as? String` I don't know if this is sustainable

Comment: it will be even more complicated if I want to add text before and after the object ? what do think?

Comment: Like I said, get the whole statement out of the cell.TextLabel.text statement. Probably a function would be best, which gets a non-null string for a key from a parse.com object. This string you should be able to use in a normal way in your statements, so they don't get polluted with the castings ...

Comment: That  looks better ;-) - I still have to dive into Swift I fear ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that you trying to concanate a String? with a String.
Just do that :

```
cell.TextLabel.text = "# " + (object?.objectForKey("topic") as! String)
```

or better

```
cell.TextLabel.text = "# " + (object?.objectForKey("topic") as? String ?? "")
```

Comment: the first one isn't working the second is working but the last quotation mark isn't working too.

Comment: I hope it won't crash :)

Comment: I edit the first one. Parenthesis was missing. 
The first one will crash if object don't have key *topic*
The second one will never crash ;)

Comment: Thanks mate , one more quick q What if I want to add before and after ?

Comment: Same Logic: 
cell.TextLabel.text = "# " + (object?.objectForKey("topic") as? String ?? "") + "#"